# Export data to txt file with fixed formated fields

Tags: vb.net

I've a code in vb that export data from datatable to a formated txt file. I've been using this code and it works, but there's a field in datable with long texts. I'd like to breake this records into multiple lines to fit a fixed-width column. The below code write all records in a unique line.

```
writer.WriteLine("{0,-4}{1,-16}{2,-16}{3,-10}{4,-50}{5,14}", txtlanc.Text, busca2.Contadc, " ", " ", busca2.Historico, busca2.Valor.ToString("f"))
```

This is the actual result(example):

1802         67894      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx           1320,00
 1802         63334      zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz           4200,50

How expected:

1802         67894      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx           1320,00

```
           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

1802         63334      zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz           4200,50

```
           zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
```

Comment: So you're asking us how to break a `String` into multiple `Strings` of a specific size. What research have you done on that subject? What have you tried to accomplish it? What happened when you tried it? SO is not a place to ask questions of the form "I want to do this, tell me how".

Comment: I tried to use "vbcrlf" and ControlChars.Tab but without success. I really dont know how to break a string based on a fixed-width chars considering a loop eather.

Comment: So you never encountered the `String.Substring` method in any of your web searches?

Comment: Substring method really  solved my problem. Thank you very much.